# Is it possible to have a case when then select and join?

Tags: sql-server

This is my query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temdb.dbo.#declaration 

SELECT * 
INTO #declaration 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         CASE 
             WHEN type_id_emet_vend = 'CIB' 
                THEN id_emetteur_vendeur 
             WHEN type_id_emet_vend = 'LEI' OR 'AFC' 
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT a.[CODE CIB] 
                      FROM [dbo].[newFILE] p1 
                      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ACTEUR] a ON p1.id_emetteur_vendeur IN ([CODE LEI], [CODE AFC])
         END AS cib_declarant;
```

I have a condition in the case when clause if the TYPE_ID_EMET_VEND = 'LEI' or 'AFC', after the then, I must display all this condition, but the query does not work, do you have other methods?

Comment: Don't use OR, use IN ('LEI', 'AFC')

Comment: `but the query does not work` = clarify what do you mean. what's the desired result?

Comment: you're right, this query makes no sense. so many problems, that it is not clear that you understand how SQL and selecting records work. I would suggest writing a somple working query which gets a portion of data you want, then write another simple working query to get the other bit of information. Then determin...can I insert these separately into my temp table? can I JOIN them, or does a UNION make sense?

Comment: You probably need to study SQL a bit more. To mention just two things:
1. if the expression "type_id_emet_vend = 'LEI' OR 'AFC'" does not give a syntax error, then it will always be evaluated as true, because 'AFC' is "true". Maybe you meant "type_id_emet_vend = 'LEI' OR type_id_emet_vend = 'AFC'".
2. The THEN clause in a CASE expression returns a scalar. If the "SELECT DISTINCT ..." query returns multiple rows, your query will fail. I don't know what you want to achieve, but I would should probably try to write the query without a CASE expression.